# Reading lists to a file (convert to int or float) in Python

Tags: python, int, readline

How do I follow these instructions?

"**4.4** **Read the numbers in the file prices.txt into a number list**.

Remember readline() reads a line from a file as a string. Make sure you do proper type conversion so the data are actually stored as numbers in the list. "

This is my code. (How do I change it to int or float?)

```
f = open ('prices.txt', 'r')
data = []
line = f.readline().strip()
data.append(line)
while line != "":
    line = f.readline().strip()
    data.append(line)
f.close()

print("File reading completed, data were read into a list")
print (data)
```

Comment: First of all, have you searched this yourself? This is basic python code...Second, what is the format of your 'prices.txt'? Why do you use `strip()`. Third, a `for in` construction would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open ('prices.txt', 'r')
data = []
line = f.readline().strip()
values = line.split();
for value in values:
    data.append(float(value));
while line != "":
    line = f.readline().strip()
    values = line.split();
    for value in values:
        data.append(float(value));

f.close()

print("File reading completed, data were read into a list")
print (data)
```